# erore SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; when i run migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i use a package for otp in laravel ([Laravel OTP Login Package](https://github.com/tpaksu/laravel-otp-login))

my migration :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('one_time_password_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigIncrements("user_id")->index();
        $table->string('otp_code')->index();
        $table->string('refer_number')->index();
        $table->string('status')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('one_time_password_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

when run migration show this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect
table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be
defined as a key (SQL: create table `one_time_password_logs` (`id` int
unsi gned not null auto_increment primary key, `user_id` bigint
unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `otp_code` varchar(255)
not null, `refer_number` varchar(255) not null, `status` varchar(255)
not null, ` created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null)
default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' engine =
innodb)

  at
C:\Users\aliaz\Desktop\smart-lighting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

  1  
C:\Users\aliaz\Desktop\smart-lighting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto
column and it must be defined as a key")

  2  
C:\Users\aliaz\Desktop\smart-lighting\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:464
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

Comment: As the error says, you can only have 1 AutoIncrement column. You are creating two with `increments` and `bigIncrements`. I'm guessing `user_id` needs to be `bigInteger` instead.

Comment: i change bigInteger and show this error: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'one_time_password_logs_user_id_foreign' are incompatible.

Comment: Make sure that the column definition for `user_id` on `one_time_password_logs` matches `id` on `users` exactly. So if `users`.`id` is integer, then `user_id` needs to be integer instead of bigInteger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Be Careful: Laravel 5.8 Added `bigIncrements` As Defaults.
- Foreign keys with migrations: don’t forget `UNSIGNED`
- `InnoDB` requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

I merged your 2 Schema. Try this :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('one_time_password_logs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('otp_code')->index();
        $table->string('refer_number')->index();
        $table->string('status')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```